# How select index in Yii2 ActiveQuery

Tags: sql, yii2

How I can have this command:

```
SELECT * FROM table USE INDEX (index1)
```

Comment: When you read the whole table, no index can improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `USE INDEX` after name of table in from section. For yii queryBuilder you can do it like this:

```
 Model::find()
 ->from(['tableAlias' => Model::tableName().' use index (index1)'])
 ->with(...)
 ->where(...) 
 //etc
```

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL I had to use this:

```
Product::find()
            ->select('product.*')
            ->from([new Expression('{{%product}} FORCE INDEX (idx__product_search)')])
```

Without specifying `->select` it would not create a proper query, because it would search in a table named `` `product FORCE INDEX(idx__product_search)` ``

Comment: Confirm that it works. Also with an inner join:
`Post::find()->select('post.*')
            ->from([new Expression('{{%post}} FORCE INDEX (indx_post_status_date)')])
            ->innerJoin('user AS user FORCE INDEX (indx_user_domain)', 'post.User_OID = user.OID')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use findBySql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table USE INDEX (index1);" 

$model = Table::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Table in this case mean your  ActiveRecord Class Name

with the function findBySql is enough that you write the sql queries you need including any joins, where clauses, and so on. findBySql actually moved as assigned to var `'$sql'` the sql database engine for runs as it is. If you want to use activeQuery, like you added in comment,  it comes to building step by step the equivalent sql command you need. In some cases the use of active query is less spontaneous than using a sql query directed especially to those who are very familiar with sql and querying db without DAO, and without ORM

Comment: I have any other params:->with(['detailPage'])
            ->joinWith('unic')
            ->groupBy('visit.unic_id')
            ->place($params['id'])
            ->skipUnknownUnic()
            ->method([2,3])
            ->Ad(@intval($params['Visit']['ad']))
            ->orderBy(['visit.id' => SORT_DESC])
//            ->indexBy('search_idx')
            ->skipAdBot();
        $column = [..............]

Comment: I have update the answer for a brief description, I think the comment you added is not in original question and 
it would be fair for you to say if the answer that was posted answers to your original question. If the answer is right would be fair  mark it as accepted and / or as useful. Any other questions should be new questions post.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$model = User::find()
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->one();
```

Comment: I have composite index: Table schema id,col1, col2    CREATE INDEX index1 ON table (col1, col2);

Comment: No, indexBy() - indexing result query

Comment: i don't  understand your question , you want select or create index.

Comment: I wont select using selectrd index

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any plain sql query using Yii2 createcommand method as shown below:

```
use yii\db\Query;
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;

$model = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table USE INDEX (index1)');
$users = $model->queryAll();
```